# Name re is not defined although re is imported in module and in main code

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm working on a Jupyter Notebook for my master's thesis and I'd like to keep it clean. I use a lot of functions to assign categories to groups of data. 
Therefore, I've decided to put all those functions in a functions.py module which I import at the start of my notebook. My notebook has the following imports:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../src/') # ugly hack to be able to import the functions module
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import functions as fn
```

One of my functions uses the "re" module for matching strings with regex. When I called the said function I get `NameError: ("name 're' is not defined", 'occurred at index 0')` so I figured I had to `import re` at the beginning of my functions.py file. This didn't change anything. So I even tried to put `import re` in the function body, but it wouldn't work either.

I have absolutely no idea why re doesn't work despite trying to import it everywhere.

*Note: my functions worked correctly when I was defining and using them from the notebook so I know for certain it's not a bug in my function.*

Comment: Did you execute the cell?

Comment: Yes of courses I did :)
edit : I also haven't been able to reproduce this issue by using .py files in a similar directory structure so it seems to be a problem of Jupyter specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own issue, the answer is stupidly simple: Jupyter doesn't take into account any edits to an imported module even if you reimport it. If you make any changes to a module you have to shut down the kernel and restart it, import again and the edits will work.

In my particular case I had added `import re` to my functions.py but Jupyter didn't take it into account until I restarted the kernel.

Comment: This is the same with a regular Python session.

Answer (score 0):

In a notebook, you can use the importlib library and call `importlib.reload(module)` instead of restarting the kernel